# Replacement of the letters in Japanese while compounding words

Tags: morphology, japanese, compounds

I've spent some time solving [Fakepapershelfmaker NACLO problem](http://www.naclo.cs.cmu.edu/assets/problems/NACLO08f.pdf), and later at solution I've read that some japanese letters do not require replacement while compounding.

In Japanese you should replace letters in the atomic words to give the compound word a specific meaning (for instance, initial *h* with *b*, initial *k* with *g*, and so on). As I've understood, this is a trick in order to exclude ambiguity.

[image]

However, [solution](http://nacloweb.org/resources/problems/2008/naclo08r2_sol.pdf) says that some letters do not require a replacement. I guess that it could lead to ambiguity of compound words. And my question is: do Japanese really has such letters? And, if yes, in which way the ambiguity in this case is excluded?

Comment: This question would fit better on the [Japanese SE](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: The classical reference on this is Ito & Mester 1986 "The phonology of voicing in Japanese", Linguistic Inquiry 17:49–73

Comment: @lemontree How come?

Comment: @Alenanno Because it's about Japanese?!

Comment: @lemontree Uhm, but we don't migrate questions about English to EL&U simply because they're about English. We do it when they're about usage, for example. This one is asking about an aspect of Japanese morphology. I may concede that it could also be on topic on Japanese SE (not sure), but even if it was, it wouldn't make it off topic here.

Comment: I never said that it is off-topic here - that's why I didn't close-vote it, because I don't think it is -, I just said it would fit *better* on Japanese SE. The question "Does Japanese have such letters?" is, although not un-linguistic, clearly more directed to specifically Japanese rather than general linguistics. And that's why, IMO, it fits scope of a Japanese-specialized site, since there already is one, better than the scope of a (genereal-)linguistics-specialized site - already simply because there are more people on Japanese SE who are able to professionally answer this question.

Comment: I would apply the same procedure to English-related questions iff they are more about English in particular rather than natural language in general (but many phenomena that occur in one language do have a linguistic explanation that is applicable to all languages, that's why we shouldn't migrate *everything*).

Comment: This is not about letters! It is about sounds - it would be no different if Japanese had never been written.

Comment: @lemontree Just noticed your comment (please ping me next time). You said *"I never said that it is off-topic here"*, that's it. It's not off topic, therefore it stays. Of course the user is free to ask (a tailored version of) the question in another site, if it fits. However, as also Colin noted, the question is more about changes in sounds than mere changes in letters, making it pretty much a linguistic question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This phenomenon is called *rendaku*, or "sequential voicing".

Many phonemes in Japanese occur in voiced/unvoiced pairs. In *kana* writing, these are distinguished with a *dakuten* "voice mark" over the voiced version: for instance, か /ka/, が /ga/.

(Side note: in a few cases this reflects historical rather than current pronunciation: /h/ voices to /b/ because it was originally /ɸ/, and /β/ isn't distinguished from /b/.)

*Rendaku* means that the first sound in the second part of a compound becomes voiced...most of the time. In reality, it's not quite this simple. There are a few additional rules:

- Branching constraints! This is what the NACLO problem is about.
- **If the sound is already voiced, nothing happens to it**
- Lyman's Law: *rendaku* doesn't happen if the second word contains any voiced obstruents
- *Rendaku* also doesn't happen in "A and B" compounds: so *yama* "mountain" + *kawa* "river" could become *yamakawa* "mountain and river" **or** *yamagawa* "river which is on a mountain"

So as you can see, *rendaku* isn't completely free from ambiguity. Already-voiced sounds such as /n/, /r/, /j/ aren't affected by it at all, which is what the footnote in the problem is pointing out. But there are also specific words which completely ignore *rendaku*, or which cause it to happen inconsistently. A few roots become voiced when attached to nouns, but not to verbs. It doesn't help that this voicing isn't indicated at all in *kanji* writing.

In these cases, the ambiguity has to be resolved the same way as in English: context, world-knowledge, and familiarity with the language.